# axios request to DRF with JWT auth fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a Django rest API with JWT auth for signup and login built with react.
When trying to log in a user I get a 403 forbidden error.

I added the csrf token to the headers of the request and I can see it in the promise when using the console, so that's not the problem here.

I just don't understand where this post is breaking

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

var csrftoken = Cookies.get("csrftoken");

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN: csrftoken,
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token")
      ? "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
      : null,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
    withCredentials: true,
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    // test for token presence, no point in sending a request if token isn't present
    if (
      localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") &&
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized"
    ) {
      const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");

      return axiosInstance
        .post("/token/refresh/", { refresh: refresh_token })
        .then((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access);
          localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", response.data.refresh);

          axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
            "JWT " + response.data.access;
          originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] =
            "JWT " + response.data.access;

          return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
    // specific error handling done elsewhere
    return Promise.reject({ ...error });
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

And the login component using the axios instance:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axiosInstance from "../axiosApi";
import DjangoCSRFToken from "django-react-csrftoken";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "", password: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post("/token/obtain/", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      });
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
        "JWT " + response.data.access;
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access);
      localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", response.data.refresh);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Login
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <DjangoCSRFToken />
          <label>
            Username:
            <input
              name="username"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Password:
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

the console when hitting submit:

[image: console output of the login page]

Comment: can you please add to your DRF function @csrf_excemp https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt and check if it works

Comment: @EddwinPaz It is working, but if I understand correctly, this is not a good move security-wise isn't it?

Comment: if you have a JWT its not necessary. JWT gives you the authentication you need. CSRF it's for session management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try removing CSRF from the call. and make use of @csrf_exepmt for further information please follow this link. [Django csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) using your JWT it's enough.

Example:

```
@csrf_exempt
def myEndpoint():
  // my code
```